# Tables in Google app engine datastore(local) got deleted automatically

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am currently working in google app engine. I was testing some feature in my local and suddenly some of the tables in my local datastore got deleted. Originally it had 20+ tables and now it is displaying only 6 tables. I thought my bin file got corrupted and tried to replace my current bin file with my back-up bin file. But, still it is showing only 6 tables instead of 20+. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you change your app / project ID?

Comment: Does it really matter for local?

Comment: From experience, data is namespaced/partitioned by app ID. If you change your app ID and restart your dev server you'll find your local datastore is empty.

Answer (score 3):

By default the local dev server keeps its data in /tmp. If you restart your machine, that directory is usually cleared.

You can specify another directory by starting the dev server with the `--datastore_path` command-line argument, as described [in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver?hl=en#Python_Using_the_Datastore).